# html multiselect images

Tags: javascript, html

I printed to the screen 16 icons (little pictures).

Now I want to be able to select icons,
and when I press a button the selected icons ids will be sent in a form.

I saw in the net only checkboxes and lists multiselect,
what's the best way to do this?

(I'm pretty new to web design)

thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a way using just plain Javascript or jQuery. I prefer the jQuery version, since it separates the click handler from the markup, instead of using inline `onclick` handlers, which are in general discouraged.

What this does is use an `input` element array, which you can create by adding `[]` to the element name. This same technique can be used on `SELECT`s and other elements, since it signals to the server that an array has been submitted, as opposed to value known by a single key.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div img {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function setFormImage(id) {
    if (id != '' && !document.getElementById('input_'+id)) {
        var img = document.createElement('input');
        img.type = 'text';
        img.id = 'input_'+id;
        img.name = 'images[]';
        img.value = id;

        document.imageSubmit.appendChild(img);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jqueryimages img').click(function(){
        setFormImage(this.id);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre><?php 

if (count($_GET['images'])) {
    print_r($_GET['images']);
}

?></pre>
<div style="float: left; width: 49%;">
    <h1>Plain ol' HTML</h1>
    1. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-1" onclick="setFormImage(this.id)"/>
    <br/>
    2. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-2" onclick="setFormImage(this.id)"/>
    <br/>
    3. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-3" onclick="setFormImage(this.id)"/>
    <br/>
    4. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-4" onclick="setFormImage(this.id)"/>
</div>
<div id="jqueryimages" style="float: left; width: 49%;">
    <h1>jQuery</h1>
    5. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-5"/>
    <br/>
    6. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-6"/>
    <br/>
    7. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-7"/>
    <br/>
    8. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="img-8"/>
</div>
<h1>Form Submit</h1>
<form name="imageSubmit" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="View Selected"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THANKS a lot! This is really helpful in my way of understanding web design

Comment: Can I use jQuery with no worries that it won't work in some browsers?

Comment: Yes. jQuery supports all browsers. It's actually much easier to use jQuery and be cross-browser compatible than to create your own custom JS, since jQuery handles many of the incompatibilities internally.

Comment: Your link is dead now

Answer (score 2):

Although jQuery isn't in your tags, you should [introduce yourself to jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).  It'll make your life easier, for what you're trying to do.  Here is the basic steps both if you use jQuery and if use just Javascript:

**With jQuery**

- Give all your icons a class and each one a unique id:

`<img src='icon1.png' data-iconID=2233 class='myIcons' />`).

- Then bind that class to a click event

`$('.myIcons').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selectIcon');
});`

- Attach form submit function to `onsubmit`:

`<form ... onsubmit="submitForm();">`

- Build `submitForm` function:

  ```
     function submitForm() {
      var csvIconIds = '';
      $.each($('.myIcons.selectIcon'), function (index, value) {
          csvIconIds += $(value).attr('data-iconID');
      });
      //submit scvIconIds here along with other form data (ajax?)
     }
  ```

**With Javascript**

Similar as above but way more complicated...

- To toggle classes see this thread: [How to add/remove a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/what-is-the-solution-to-remove-add-a-class-in-pure-javascript)
- To getting attributes by class see this site: http://www.actiononline.biz/web/code/how-to-getelementsbyclass-in-javascript-the-code/

Comment: THANKS a lot! I entered the site and started reading,
seems like jQuery is going to be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var idArray = [];
$("#container-id img").each(function(index,value){
idArray.push($(value).attr("id"));
});
//do anything with the array
```