# Show/hide multiple classes with javascript

Tags: javascript, class, show-hide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the solution to remove/add a class in pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/what-is-the-solution-to-remove-add-a-class-in-pure-javascript)

Firstly forgive what seems to be a simple javascript question, I have just started getting to grasps with the language. I have seen numerous posts on showing and hiding content by either classes or ids, but they all seem to apply to one at a time. I would like to change three classes at a time and what display change is depends on what links the user has all ready clicked on. Confusing explanation I know but my example with code is below.

I am building an image gallery with a series of thumbnails that all have classes assigned to them; `.photo`, `.print` and `.logo`. The desire is to have four 'buttons'; photo, print, logo and display all. When the user clicks "photo" the code will set .photo to `display:block`, and `.print` and .logo to `display:none`. When the user clicks "print" the code will set .print to `display:block`, and .photo and .logo to `display:none`. When the user clicks "logo" the code will set .logo to `display:block`, and .photo and .print to `display:none`. And obviously when the user clicks "display all" all classes are set to `display:block`.

```
<div id="menu">
<ul class"toplevel">
<li id="photoselect"><a href="photo.html">Photography</a></li>
<li id="logoselect"><a href="logo.html">Print</a></li>
<li id="printselect"><a href="print.html">Logo</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<a href="photo/photo01.jpg" class="" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb photo" src="photo/photo01.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo02.jpg" class="" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb photo" src="photo/photo02.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo03.jpg" class="" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb print" src="photo/photo03.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo04.jpg" class="" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb print" src="photo/photo04.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo05.jpg" class="" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb logo" src="photo/photo05.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo06.jpg" class="" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb logo" src="photo/photo06.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could take advantage of css3 (for browser which support it)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content > input.hidden{ display:none; }
#content > a{ display:none; }
#po:checked ~ a.photo{ display:block; }
#pi:checked ~ a.print{ display:block; }
#lo:checked ~ a.logo{ display:block; }
#al:checked ~ a{ display:block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul class"toplevel">
<li><label for="po">Photography</label></li>
<li><label for="pi">Print</label></li>
<li><label for="lo">Logo</label></li>
<li><label for="al">All</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<input type="radio" name="bfc" id="po" class="hidden" />
<input type="radio" name="bfc" id="pi" class="hidden" />
<input type="radio" name="bfc" id="lo" class="hidden" />
<input type="radio" name="bfc" id="al" class="hidden" />
<a href="photo/photo01.jpg" class="photo" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb" src="photo/photo01.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo02.jpg" class="photo" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb" src="photo/photo02.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo03.jpg" class="print" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb" src="photo/photo03.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo04.jpg" class="print" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb" src="photo/photo04.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo05.jpg" class="logo" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb" src="photo/photo05.jpg"></a>
<a href="photo/photo06.jpg" class="logo" rel="lightbox" title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute"><img class="thumb" src="photo/photo06.jpg"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea of how to do it without any libraries (and with the HTML you posted), here's a basic way of going about it:

1. Add an event listener on the link you want to respond to a `click` event for
2. On click, go through all of the matching elements and change their style

It's good to cache your `photos` `prints` and `logos` so that you don't have to query for them on each click.

```
var content = document.getElementById('content'); 
var photos = content.getElementsByClassName('photo');
var prints = content.getElementsByClassName('print');
var logos = content.getElementsByClassName('logo');

function changeDisplay(elements, display) {
  var i = 0, l = elements.length;
  for( ; i < l; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = display;
  }
}

document.getElementById('photoselect').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  changeDisplay(prints, 'none');
  changeDisplay(logos, 'none');
  changeDisplay(photos, 'block');
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, doing this without the need for a library is why I asked if there was a Javascript solution. I would prefer a pure HTML/CSS solution but until the browsers catch up I don't believe we can rely on CSS3 yet.

I will give this a go. I'm assuming two aspects here:

1. The four lines at the top, they are the cache? I expect that speeds up the process or reduces the code you need to write?

2. The section at the bottom will be command attached to the 'photoselct' button/link, and this will be repeated for each button/link?

Comment: Exactly; by cache I just meant the 3 arrays of elements that you reuse in each event listener. You just need to add a listener for each button.