# DOM not updating after adding a class to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that collects all class names in a `div`, stores them in an `array` and pushes them all back to the DOM with a class called `blue` at the end, this is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>some title</title>
  <style>
    .blue{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="someClass otherClass" id="box"></div>
    <button id="btn">click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The thing is, I know how to get all the class names inside the `div` and even how to push `blue` (on `btn` click) inside of that div together with the other values I have collected but why isn't the blue box showing up? What am I missing?

```
var domManipulation = function(){
      var box = document.querySelector('#box');
      var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
      var class_list = [];

      if(box.classList.length > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < box.classList.length; i++){
          class_list.push(box.classList[i]);
        }
      }

      btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
          class_list.push("blue");
          box.classList.add(class_list);
          console.log(class_list);
      });

 }();
```

Here is a [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/ditosi/edit?html,js,console,output) and I can't use **jQuery** btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/remove a class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: I know how to add/push it, the problem is that I was expecting the blue box to show up after clicking the button. I might change the question because I think it's misleading.

Comment: Yes I believe it might be - reword as the way it stands, adding "blue" class seems to be the issue here...also denote HOW you know that the class was/is added properly etc.

Comment: Will it validate whether the class name is just an attribute or it really exists in the `style` tag in the `head` section?

Comment: I know because I'm logging it and it shows up

Comment: You log the array but what about the DOM?, I suspect that the array with commas is not a proper class list herel  Note that this is a "teaching" site thus I am NOT being snarky here just pointing out assumptions that seem to be made....

Comment: the class `blue` does exist in the head section, I don't need to check if the class exists, I just need to push it to the dom sort of speak.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss you're right, I'm logging the array itself, how do I check if the DOM has received that class name?

Comment: `var isBlue = document.getElementsByClassName('blue');
if (isBlue.length > 0) {`  OR use the browser and the development tools...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
box.classList.add(class_list);
```

You can't add a whole array of classes because they end up being comma-separated.

```js
var domManipulation = function() {
  var box = document.querySelector('#box');
  var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  var class_list = [];

  if (box.classList.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < box.classList.length; i++) {
      class_list.push(box.classList[i]);
    }
  }

  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    class_list.push("blue");
    class_list.forEach(function(e){
      box.classList.add(e);
    })
    console.log(class_list);
  });

}();
```

```css
#box {height: 50px; background: #eee}
#box.blue {background: blue}
```

```html
<div class="someClass otherClass" id="box"></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure the OP wants `box.className = class_list.join(' ');`

Comment: Yeah, I also gave an example of iterating the list and keeping 'classList.add'

Comment: I tried `className` but it didn't really work though. This answer does the job pretty well, thanks mate.

Comment: You're welcome, but `className` should work as well.

Comment: Yep, this is what seems to be needed here to actually add the class.