# Pure Javascript add style on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

In jQuery I know how to solve this, but in pure Javascript I don't have any idea.

When click on chevron down my content show, but when show I want to change chevron to be chevron up.

I don't know how to do an 'on click' to change the style and set the following:

`transform: rotate(180deg);`.

Toggle effect, when click again to return chevron down and repeatly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/35507/)

#### HTML:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consedier tu 
</p>
<div id="show-more-footer" onclick="myFunction()">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>


<div id="full-text">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Seo Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seo Link nummer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Number 3 Seo Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Seo Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seo Link nummer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Number 3 Seo Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Number 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Seo Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seo Link nummer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Number 3 Seo Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('full-text');
    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

#### CSS:

```
#show-more-footer{
  cursor:pointer;
}
#full-text{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: project and members not allowed me that

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: If you want a code that runs on more then one browser, i would strongly advise you to talk to your project members again. I have done big javascript projects before jquery and similar frameworks existed, would never do that again...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can directly change style of an element in **JavaScript**:

```
element.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
```

This will appear **in the HTML** as :

```
<div id="element-id" style="transform: rotate(180deg);"></div>
```

You could also use the **classList API** and **JS** :

```
.reverse {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

And the **JS** :

```
element.onclick = function() {
 element.classList.toggle("reverse");
}
```

[MDN - element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
[CanIUse - classList](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist)
The fact that some browsers don't support the `.toggle()`method is not a problem, use a custom function which uses `.add()`or `.remove()`.
**Last advices (optional) :**
I would use *CSS transitions* with this kind of features (like `transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;`) and change your hide/show method by setting a `height:0` and `overflow:hidden` to the content you hide, and `onclick` of the chevron you give him `element.style.height: auto`.

Comment: I don't know how to implement on my project in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/35507/

Comment: @ml92 What don't you understand ? Just replace `element` by your `#show-more-footer` `div`. Or maybe you have to apply this to multiple elements ? In that case you have to get the `event` source in the function to be sure it will act on the right blocks. I'm here to answer if needed

Comment: Not working, I don't know why https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/35510/
Thanks in advance, br

Comment: @ml92 you can check my demonstration pen [here](http://codepen.io/AymDev/pen/ygPNbB) and if my answer solved your problem, accept it

Comment: you are confused me with your codepen, I posted jsfiddle with my state, can you implement in my project. https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/35507/
I will accept you

Comment: Hi @ml92 I am not familiar to jsfiddle, I created an account and modified your fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aymdev/fNPvf/35571/)

Comment: Thank you so much, is it possible to add transition smooth slide down and up

Comment: @ml92 I tried with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aymdev/fNPvf/35577/) , setting the `height` to `500px`, I'd have prefered the `auto` value but the smooth transition wouldn't execute and I'm a bit busy to search for a solution for hours ;-) I hope you understand well how it works !

Answer (score 0):

my first advice would be to not use inline javascript to call your function, you should use a listener instead

```
var button = document.getElementById('show-more-footer');
button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

then you can use the callback first argument to get your event

```
function myFunction(event) {
        var button = event.currentTarget;
    var x = document.getElementById('full-text');
    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
        button.querySelector('i').style.transform = 'rotate(0)'
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        button.querySelector('i').style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'
    }
}
```

Comment: are you passing the `event` parameter to the function?

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean

Comment: this: `function myFunction(event) {`