# removeClass is not a function in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to this directive in AngularJS and would need some help to get this javascript function to work. It was okay when I just used plain JavaScript outside the angular directive. But now I have hit some problems.

It's okay down to the function `navigate` and I get an error that:

> removeClass is not a function

It works with `addClass` so I don't understand why remove doesn't work here.

```
<ol class="content">
    <li>
        "{{ myData.quotes[0].quote }}"
        <br /> <div class="quoteLine"></div> <span class="boldText"> {{ myData.quotes[0].person }} </span>
    </li>

    <li>
        "{{ myData.quotes[1].quote }}"
        <br /> 
        <div class="quoteLine"></div> <span class="boldText"> {{ myData.quotes[1].person }} </span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

```
app.directive('myCarousel', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            var next = $element.find('.next');
            var prev = $element.find('.prev');
            var items = $element.find('.content li');
            var counter = 0;
            var amount = items.length;
            var current = items[0];

            $element.addClass('active')

            function navigate (direction) {
                current.removeClass('current')
                counter = counter + direction

          if (direction === -1 && counter < 0) { 
            counter = amount - 1
          }

          if (direction === 1 && !items[counter]) { 
            counter = 0
          }

              current = items[counter]
              current.addClass('current')
            }

            // go to next quote
            next.on('click', function (ev) {
              navigate(1)
            })

            // go back to previous quote
            prev.on('click', function (ev) {
              navigate(-1)
            })

            navigate(0)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to log `current`? Maybe there's a mistake somewhere and `.find('.content li')` returns an empty list?

Comment: var items = $element.find('.content li'); this is probably filled wrongly . Inspect your genereted html and use the dev tools of browser to check if your selector is correct

Comment: mmmm could it be you are invoking `current.removeClass('current')` before `current.addClass('current')` ? how can you remove what there isnt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/remove a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344281/5535245).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `removeClass` method is a jQuery or [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) method. The raw element needs to be wrapped:

```
var items = $element.find('.content li');
var counter = 0;
var amount = items.length;
var current = items[0];

$element.addClass('active')

function navigate (direction) {
    ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶.̶r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶C̶l̶a̶s̶s̶(̶'̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶'̶)̶
    //WRAP raw element
    var $current = angular.element(current);
    $current.removeClass('current')
    counter = counter + direction
```

For more information, see [AngularJS `angular.element` API Reference - jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `current` variable is not a `jQLite` instance, so in order to use `removeClass` you have to wrap it with `jQLite` like so:

```
angular.element(current).removeClass('current')
```

Sencondly, the variable `items` is probably empty because `$element.find('.content li')` can't be used like that if you are using pure [`jQLite`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), because if so, the method `find` would be limited to look up by tag name only. So if you need to use that complex selector, you should try `$element[0].querySelectorAll('.content li')` or use old school `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

You could, if you wanted, rather than use Javascript to manipulate the classes to show and hide your text quotes, pass in your quotes to your directive and have the directive itself figure out which to show and which not to (might be a more "angular way" of doing things).

For example, something like the following directive:

```
app.directive('myCarousel', function () {
return {
    scope: {
    quotes: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: 'myCarousel.html',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    controller: function($scope) {
    let ctrl = this;

    ctrl.previousQuote = previousQuote;
    ctrl.nextQuote = nextQuote;

    let selectedQuoteId = 0;
    ctrl.selectedQuote = $scope.quotes[selectedQuoteId];

    function previousQuote() {
        if (selectedQuoteId !== 0) {
        selectedQuoteId--;
        ctrl.selectedQuote = $scope.quotes[selectedQuoteId];  
        }
    }

    function nextQuote() {
        if (selectedQuoteId + 1 < $scope.quotes.length) {
        selectedQuoteId++;
        ctrl.selectedQuote = $scope.quotes[selectedQuoteId];  
        }
    }
    }
}
});
```

And the myCarousel.html template:

```
<div>
<ol class="content">
<li>
    "{{ctrl.selectedQuote.quote}}"
    <br /> <div class="quoteLine"></div> <span class="boldText"> {{ctrl.selectedQuote.person}} </span>
</li>
</ol>
<button ng-click="ctrl.previousQuote()"><</button>
<button ng-click="ctrl.nextQuote()">></button>
</div>
```

This is figuring out which quote object is currently selected (selectedQuote) and then outputs it within the template.

Then you can just pass in your quote data from anywhere.

If you're interested, you can view it in action at this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vA80sTdjwClWvF4T4dbd