# How to change a html class with js?

Tags: javascript

I would like to change a HTML class with JavaScript!

```
    <div class="not-submitted-check" data-submit-check>
     <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Thank you for contacting us,
     <button type="button" class="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
```

I want the div class to change when i press the submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" data-submit-button>submit</button>

const submitButton = document.querySelector("[data-submit-button]");
submitButton.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
```

I want to create a function where the moment i press the button the classes change one with another

Comment: What have you already tried and/or researched?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add/remove a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: This answer is easily found on internet, next time before you ask a question do a search, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
element.classList.remove("oldclass");
element.classList.add("newclass");
```